# Using an eval()-like function to set a variable in Vim

Tags: vim

In a script, I have the following *not working* code:

```
set eval(rules[formatoption])=value
```

where `rules` is a dictionary and `formatoption` and `value` are a variable. I want to make Vim read the variable name from `rules[formatoption]` and set it to `value`. How can I make Vim set a variable this way? I think there should be a function like `setvar(name, value)`or something similar, that sets `name`(string) to `value`. That line of code would save me from writing about 30 lines of code in a 70 lines script.

Comment: reallife example here: **[`:exec &nu==&rnu? "se nu!" : "se rnu!"`](http://superuser.com/a/339595)**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `:execute`:

```
execute 'set' rules[formatoption] . '=value'
```

You can also change Vim options via `:let &optionname = ...`, but that doesn't help here. There's also the obscure `:help curly-braces-names`, but that won't work here, neither.